# ng-sidebar to create a sidebar that pushes content to the right

Tags: css, angular

I am using ng-sidebar to animate and implement the collapsable sidebar on smaller mobile screens.

This is my first time using Angular so I apologize if the question is simple for everyone else.

I have installed using npm install ng-sidebar and tried the working demo, but I have difficulty adjusting it to my needs.

In my app.component.html I have this code taken from the demo :

```
<ng-sidebar-container>
 <ng-sidebar
  [(opened)]="_opened"
  [mode]="_MODES[_modeNum]"
  [closeOnClickOutside]="_closeOnClickOutside"
  [closeOnClickBackdrop]="_closeOnClickBackdrop"
  [showBackdrop]="_showBackdrop"
  [animate]="_animate">

  <button (click)="_toggleOpened()">Close sidebar</button>
  <p><a closeSidebar>This will close the sidebar too</a></p>
  <hr>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item collapsed side" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a>              
        </li>  
       <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="home">
        <li class="nav-item list-unstyled"> <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home/submenu">Submenu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item list-unstyled">
               <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home/submenu2">Submenu2</a>
                </li>
        <li class="nav-item side">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/secondMenu"MenuItem>/a>
        </li>
            </ul>
</ng-sidebar>
<div ng-sidebar-content>
  <header class="demo-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button"  (click)="_toggleOpened()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

    <span>ng-sidebar</span>
  </header>
  <section class="demo-contents">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </section>
</div>
```

What I do not understand is, how to put a  :

```
<button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

That when clicked, called

```
_toggleOpened() and [mode]="_MODES[_modeNum]"
```

- mode should be push

[Example link](https://echeung.me/ng-sidebar/)

And have it on the top bar as in the example. Because no css style is applied on my document when trying the demo.

How do I make that button and sidebar to only push the content as in the link when clicking mode-push, and also add transparent background ?
So the button should push the content, add background and when clicking anywhere outside on the screen to be closed. ?

I'm very sorry again, I just need a simple layout to help me get started :| To understand it

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you just need to call a function when clicking on a button?  Simply do <button (click)="myfunction()"></button>

Comment: But can I call multiple functions ?
Because one of the functions toggles to the right, the other one pushes the content and the other one makes background transparent ?

Comment: you have in the button (click)="_toggleOpened()". The function _toggleOpened() must be in your code. Only make "this._opened = !this._opened;". In the component you have [(opened)]="_opened". That's you can observer if there are a change on the variable (see the @input and the ngOnChanges...)